# atom autocomplete-plus without semicolon

Tags: atom-editor

How to config `autocomplete-plus` to suggest javascript without semicolon?

For example, I input `log` in atom, `autocomplete-plus` suggest `console.log();`.
I don't need the `;`, how to config `autocomplete-plus` to remove `;` when suggest.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add custom snippet to replace the default one. In order to do that open command palette `Ctrl+Shift+P`, search for `Application: Open your Snippets` and write a snippet for `.source.js` scope:

```
'.source.js':
  'Log without ;':
    'prefix': 'log'
    'body': 'console.log()'
```

To override the default snippet you have to set prefix to `log`. If you want to learn more about snippets you can visit [Flight Manual](http://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/snippets/).

Answer (score 4):

You can add a custom [snippet](http://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/snippets/):

1. Open the command palette with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.
2. Search for `Application: Open your Snippets`.
3. Add the folowing code:

   ```
   '.source.js':
     'Console log without ;':
       'prefix': 'log'
       'body': 'console.log($1)$2'
   ```